# Show $A^T$ has an eigenvector with all components rational

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Matrix $A$ is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with rational entries such that $(1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{4}, \sqrt{5})^T$ is an eigenvector of A. Show that $A^T$ has eigenvector with all components rational.

My idea is: let the eigenvalue associated with the above eigenvector be $λ$. Since all matrix entries are rational numbers so an irrational number will be linearly independent. Use this

$2(a_{11} + 2a_{14}) = a_{41} + 2a_{44}$

$a_{21}+2a_{24} = 0$

$a_{31}+2a_{34} = 0$

$a_{51}+2a_{54} = 0$

but I can't find transposed matrix's eigenvector.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote.

Comment: @5xum I'm sorry that I didn't add my idea.

Comment: Not a problem. I retracted my votes.

Comment: @SGtjdqls0599 What is the $T$ in $\sqrt{T}$?  Is it an arbitrary integer?  indeterminate?

Comment: @ErickWong I'm sorry it's typo sqrt(T) is sqrt(5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v = (1, \sqrt{2}, \sqrt{3}, \sqrt{4}, \sqrt{5})^T$ and assume $A v = \lambda v$. From the first row we get
$$a_{1,1} + 2 a_{1,4} + a_{1,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{1,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{1,5} \sqrt{5} = \lambda$$
From the second row we get:
$$a_{2,1} + 2 a_{2,4} + a_{2,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{2,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{2,5} \sqrt{5} = \lambda \sqrt{2}$$
Now substitute $\lambda$:
$$a_{2,1} + 2 a_{2,4} + a_{2,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{2,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{2,5} \sqrt{5} = (a_{1,1} + 2 a_{1,4} + a_{1,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{1,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{1,5} \sqrt{5}) \sqrt{2}$$
Multiply and rearrange the terms:
$$a_{2,1} + 2 a_{2,4} - 2a_{1,2} + (a_{2,2}-a_{1,1}-2a_{1,4}) \sqrt{2} + a_{2,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{2,5} \sqrt{5} - a_{1,3} \sqrt{6} - a_{1,5} \sqrt{10} = 0$$
Since the roots of the squarefree positive integers are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, we obtain in particular $a_{1,3} = 0$ and $a_{1,5} = 0$,
so
$$\lambda = a_{1,1} + 2a_{1,4} + a_{1,2} \sqrt{2}.$$
From the third row we get:
$$a_{3,1} + 2 a_{3,4} + a_{3,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{3,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{3,5} \sqrt{5} = \lambda \sqrt{3}$$
Again, substitute $\lambda$:
$$a_{3,1} + 2 a_{3,4} + a_{3,2} \sqrt{2} + a_{3,3} \sqrt{3} + a_{3,5} \sqrt{5} = (a_{1,1} + 2a_{1,4} + a_{1,2} \sqrt{2}) \sqrt{3}$$
Multiply and rearrange the terms:
$$a_{3,1} + 2 a_{3,4} + a_{3,2} \sqrt{2} + (a_{3,3}-a_{1,1}-2a_{1,4}) \sqrt{3} + a_{3,5} \sqrt{5} - a_{1,2} \sqrt{6} = 0$$
So we obtain $a_{1,2} = 0$ and
$$\lambda = a_{1,1} + 2 a_{1,4}$$
Thus $\lambda \in \mathbb{Q}$. Since $A^T$ and $A$ have the same set of eigenvalues, $A^T$ is a matrix with rational components and a rational eigenvalue. Therefore $A^T$ has an eigenvector with rational components.